# Algorithm for update state (DB) of Objects inside another Object (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have list of Boxes. Each Box have numbered slots for books (№1, №2 ... №20) and 0-20 Books (`List<Book>`) inside it at specific position - some slots may be empty and some books marked as read.

I have 2 tables in DB, where stored info about **boxes**: BoxId, Color, etc..
**books**: BoxId, BookNumber and state(Read/Empty).

Example: [B15649] - [Book4] - [Read].

It shows that Box B15649 **contain** a Book in Slot№4 and this Book is **read**.

I need to create table with all boxes, state of books in it and update it in `OnGet`.

[How table is suppose to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGS5Z.png)

I think of smth like this

```
 public async Task OnGet(string color)
        {
            //Get all boxes with specific color
            BoxCollection = await db.BoxInfo.Include(x => x.BookInfo).Where(y => y.Color == color).ToListAsync();
            
            //Get list of all books
            BookListFromDb = Select * boxes from db.AllBookInfo where boxId in 
            [boxId1, boxId2 ... ]
            //I need to get this boxIds from BoxCollection above

            //Update all states of books for all boxes
            foreach (var box in BoxCollection)
            {
                var boxId = box.boxId - to see what box it is
                bookListForBoxId = BookListFromDb.where(x=>x.boxId == boxId).ToList - choose all books in this box (there may be 0-20 items)

                //... - create new list of books, which i'll fill in forloop
                NewBookList<Book> newBookList = new NewBookList<Book>();//... - create new list of books, which i'll fill in forloop
                for(short i =1; i<=20; i++) {
                  //i need to fill all slots, so Slot№ = i
                  //if bookListForBoxId contain book at this slot, then it is exist and
                  //i can check for IsRead, if not - i create Slot with false, false
                  newBookList.Add(Slot№ = i, IsExist = true/false and IsRead = true/false 
                 }
                //Replace List<Book> in this box with newBookList
                box.BookList = newBookList;

            }
        }
```

And in html I just show each book for each box

Maybe you have another ideas, i'm not sure it's the right way to do it

Comment: Can you provide your model structure, View page and how to call `OnGet` method? I can't reproduce your structure according to the code you provided.

Comment: In addition, your code seems to update the status of all eligible Books according to the `Color` field. I think it should be updated through the corresponding `BookId`. For example, if you have read a book, you can locate the Id of the book, then retrieve it from the database, and only change the status of this book. Of course this is just my suggestion as I'm not really sure about your structure and what you want in the end.